# Identity groups where the square of each element is the neutral element

Tags: abstract-algebra

I need to identity all groups G where $\forall g \in G: g^2$ is the neutral element of G applies.

This does apply for all groups with 1 or 2 elements, but not for groups with 3 elements. It seems clear that each element (except for the neutral element) need to be of order 2. But how does this help me to identity all groups for which this applies?

[Edit]

It seems that those groups need to be abelian, and (what is trivial to show) all products of $\mathbb{Z}_2$. But are all those groups isomorphic to a product of $\mathbb{Z}_2$? How do I know if I got *all* matching groups?

Comment: Hint: there are groups that fulfill this of any order any non-negative power of $\;2\;$ (and also infinite ones), and all of them are abelian.

Comment: @Timbuc thanks for your hint, I added some thoughts to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These groups are abelian, in fact $\mathbb{F}_2$-vector spaces and therefore $\cong \mathbb{F}_2^{\oplus S}$ for some set $S$. (They are *not* necessarily of the form $\mathbb{F}_2^S$ for some set $S$.)

Comment: thanks for your answer. But how can be shown that it is **only** those vector spaces?

Comment: Hint: $g^2=e$ means $2g=0$ in additive notation, and $\mathbb{F}_2=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @muffel: Write down the definition of "abelian group of exponent $2$" and "vector space over $\mathbf{F}_2$", and you'll see they are essentially the same. Alternatively, construct a bijection between the class of all abelian groups of exponent $2$ and the class of all vector spaces over $\mathbf{F}_2$. Incidentally, the same idea works if you replace $2$ with any prime.

Comment: @Hurkyl thanks for your comment! I'll try to figure this out using your idea of a bijection